# Can someone assist with pinpoint the bug in my SQL double JOIN query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am attempting to execute a sql query using two joins.

The query can be described like so. I have three tables (accounts, reverification_trackers, and verifications). What I want to do is to select all the accounts that have a level -20 attribute. From those accounts, I only want those that have a populated reverification_tracker association and have no verification associations.

To illustrate my use case:

- If an account with level -20 has no reverification_tracker and a verification, I
  don't want it.
- If an account with level -20 has a reverification_tracker and a verification, I don't want it
- If an account with level -20 has a reverification_tracker and no verification, I do want it.

I

The query looks like this:

```
Account.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM accounts a WHERE a.level = -20
                    INNER JOIN reverification_trackers rt ON rt.account_id = a.id
                     LEFT JOIN verifications v ON v.account_id = a.id 
                    WHERE v.account_id IS NULL ")
```

This is the error I receive:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INNER"
```

I've been working on this for over an hour and I'm pretty sure I have the correct joins but I don't see my syntax error. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always a good idea to stick with the `active_record` methods rather than using `find_by_sql`, unless it is absolutely necessary for performance reasons or something else.

The advantage of sticking with the `active_record` methods is that you don't need to worry about the adapter specific sql. For example: this sql that you have here may work in postgres but may not work if you switch to mysql.

Based on your sql, assuming you have the following models:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reverification_trackers
  has_many :verifications
end

class ReverificationTracker < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
end

class Verification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
end
```

You could use the following in order to get all the accounts that have level -20 attribute, and have a populated reverification_tracker but not  verification.

```
Account.where(level: -20)
       .includes(:reverification_trackers, :verifications)
       .where.not(reverification_trackers: { id: nil })
       .where(verification: { id: nil })
```

You could even set these as scopes for re-usability:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reverification_trackers
  has_many :verifications

  scope :with_reverification_trackers, -> { includes(:reverification_trackers).where.not(reverification_trackers: { id: nil }) }
  scope :without_verifications, -> { includes(:verifications).where(verification: { id: nil }) }
end
```

And use them as follows:

```
Account.where(level: -20).with_reverification_trackers.without_verifications
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you have two where clauses?

What about this:

```
Account.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM accounts a 
                INNER JOIN reverification_trackers rt ON rt.account_id = a.id
                 LEFT JOIN verifications v ON v.account_id = a.id 
                WHERE v.account_id IS NULL 
                AND a.level = -20")
```

Answer (score 0):

your syntax is incorrect:  try this:

```
"SELECT * 
 FROM accounts a 
 INNER JOIN reverification_trackers rt ON rt.account_id = a.id
 LEFT JOIN verifications v ON v.account_id = a.id 
 WHERE v.account_id IS NULL 
 AND a.level = -20
```